# How to plot recursive function in matplotlib.pyplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, recursion

I'm trying to plot a recursive function I had made that measures growth over time. Here is the function:

```
def pop(start_pop, years, percentage_change, max_pop):
    if years == 0:
         return start_pop
    else:
         changes = pop(start_pop,years-1,percentage_change,max_pop)
         return changes + (1-changes/max_pop)*percentage_change*changes

print(pop(600,85,0.1,20000))
```

Which gives me the output of:

```
19879.4425
```

How can I plot this function of the graph, where "years" is on the x-axis and "max_pop" is on the y-axis?

Thanks for your help!

**Note:** If it helps, I'm wanting/ expecting once plotted that the curve will look something similar to a learning curve.

Comment: If you want to plot a function `f(x, otherargs)` at values `x = [1,2,3,...]` you evaluate the function on the list, e.g.  `y = [f(i, otherargs) for i in x]` and plot `plt.plot(x,y)`.

Comment: To add to @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, since it's a recursive function it keep calculating from 1. It will be helpful if you have a global cache so you don't do a lot of repeating calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just add a list at the top:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
changes_plot=[]
def pop(start_pop, years, percentage_change, max_pop):
    if years == 0:
         return start_pop
    else:
        changes = pop(start_pop,years-1,percentage_change,max_pop)
        changes_plot.append(changes)
        return changes + (1-changes/max_pop)*percentage_change*changes

pop(600,85,0.1,20000)
plt.plot(changes_plot)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for!